# Transform a backgorund image into an object problem

Tags: html, css

i dont know how to transform this background into an object and put it into a button for my menu, because the text and the image overlays.
I need help to transform the background image (the little png) into an object so the text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit" couldnt overlay with it
i dont know if you understand, im not that good at english, thank you so much

```css
.menu22 {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.menu22 li {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/SyCRm7z/1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 15px center;
  position: relative;

}

.menu22 li:hover {
   color: #404040 !important;
 font-weight: 700 !important;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/SyCRm7z/1.png");
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.menu22 a{
  display: block;
  padding: 23px 0;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu22">
   <li><a href="#">object1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">object3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
   <li><a href="#">object5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li><br>
</ul>
```

Comment: simply add padding-left:Xpx (the space taken by the image)

Answer (score 0):

Added some padding to anchor tag : padding-left:15%;

```css
.menu22 {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.menu22 li {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/SyCRm7z/1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 15px center;
  position: relative;

}

.menu22 li:hover {
   color: #404040 !important;
 font-weight: 700 !important;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/SyCRm7z/1.png");
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    padding-left:6%;
}
  .menu22 a{
  display: block;
  padding: 23px 0;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left:15%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu22">
   <li><a href="#">object1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">object3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></li>
   <li><a href="#">object5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li><br>
</ul>
```

Comment: is not that i want, i need that the png became an object and the text isnt able to overlay it  like a <img> </img> <p></p>

Comment: Not sure what your are asking, can you please share any example..

Answer (score 0):

Add another div tag inside li tag and make it that background css picture is inside div, not the background of li tag itself.